# Not able to use the loaded Image data properly

Tags: c++, qt, qimage

I load a Image from raw data and use `QImage::Format_MonoLSB` format while loading. I try to write to a file, and I get the image in the B&W mono color format. Which is Ok.

What is the way to get an image out of it in a color format ? Eg: if I want to color the While portions to a particular color, how do I do it ?

I tried to create a `QImage` using `QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied`, and used painter to draw the one got from above using a pen/brush. But that does not seem to work. I suspect there is a compatibility issue between formats.

```
   colorImage = QImage(QRect(0, 0, w, h), QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
   _painter.begin(&blockImage);
   _painter.setPen(Qt::blue);
   _painter.drawImage(QRect(0, 0, w, h), blockImage, aboveImage);
   _painter.end();
```

I tried to change the loading code to use a color format `(Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied`), but it does not seem to work either. I get no image in the output.

Answer (score 0):

You're drawing `blockImage` on `blockImage`. I think you want to paint on the `colorImage` instead: `_painter.begin(&colorImage);`

Anyway, I would use [`QImage::convertToFormat`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qimage.html#convertToFormat-2) and pass in a color table instead.